# How can I get the velocity of a rigid body?

Tags: python

Is it possible to get the velocity of a rigid body?

Comment: Once a sim is baked, the global location at any frame is `ob.matrix_world.translation`  Velocity and Acceleration can  be "baked" from this data.  (Using `numpy gradient` for example) AFAIK there is no exposed velocity property.